# How can I make a list horizontally scrollable without items going to the second line?

Tags: html, css

I have a list of items:

```
<div class="dates-bar">
    <ul>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>...</li>
      <li>30</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

I need this bar to be in a single line. I don't know how to achieve that. I have tried the following:

```
.dates-bar {
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: scroll;
}

.dates-bar ul {
   width: 500%;
}

.dates-bar li {
   display: inline-block;
   margin: 0 10px;
}
```

The problem here is that, if the numbers items cross get to the end of the bar, it will wrap the items to the second line and if the number of items is small, there will be a huge gap at the end of this bar. With some tweaking I can fix the latter one. However, I don't know what to do, so that the items don't go over the second line.

Comment: I don't think you can do it if you don't know the width of ul. but let's wait for the answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.dates-bar{
    width:auto;
    max-width:100%
    overflow-x: atuo;
}

.dates-bar ul{
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

The whitespace property is the missing ingredient.

Answer (score 1):

Set your UL to `display:flex;`

```css
.dates-bar {
    width: 150px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
}

.dates-bar ul {
  display:flex;
}  

.dates-bar li {
   display: inline-block;
   margin: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="dates-bar">
    <ul>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
      <li>4</li>
      <li>5</li>
      <li>...</li>
      <li>30</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Since the `<li>` are `display:inline-block` they are treated as inline flex items making the flex coniainer (the `<ul>`) expand to contain all elements. At least that is how I read the spec. http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/#flex-items

Answer (score 1):

You can use `display: flex;` for this:

```
.dates-bar { 
  width: 100%; 
 } 
.dates-bar ul { 
  width: 500%; 

  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: no-wrap;
}
.dates-bar li { 
  display: inline-block; 
  margin: 0 10px; 

  flex: 0 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: @Gasim display:flex is amazing, newest browsers support it, you'll have some trouble with older browsers... https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 1):

Try this CSS:

```
.dates-bar li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 10px;
}
.dates-bar {
   width: auto;
   overflow-x: scroll;
}
.dates-bar ul {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wfxhuwvc/